# Xml parsing issue in java

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xpath

this is my xml to parse..

```
<object pk="1" model="test">
    <field type="BigIntegerField" name="number">100809206</field>
    <field type="CharField" name="id">11700632</field>
    <field name="test123">
        <object pk="1" model="employee">
            <field type="DateTimeField" name="updated_on">27 Nov, 2014, 17:18 hrs</field>
            <field type="CharField" name="EmployeeName">ABC</field>
        </object>
        <object pk="2" model="employee">
            <field type="DateTimeField" name="updated_on">28 Nov, 2014, 17:18 hrs</field>
            <field type="CharField" name="EmployeeName">XYZ</field>
        </object>
        <object pk="3" model="employee">
            <field type="DateTimeField" name="updated_on">28 Nov, 2014, 17:18 hrs</field>
            <field type="CharField" name="EmployeeName">XYZ</field>
        </object>
    </field>
</object>
```

My code

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpsURLConnection.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
{
    response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();

if(response != null && !"".contains(response))
{
    SAXBuilder saxBuilder = new SAXBuilder();
    Document doc = saxBuilder.build(new StringReader(response.toString()));
    Element rootEle = doc.getRootElement();
    List childList = rootEle.getChildren();
    System.out.println(childList.toString());
    for(i=0;i<childList.size();i++)
    {
        Element shipment= (Element) childList.get(i);
        if(shipment != null)
        {
            List dataList  = shipment.getChildren();
            if(dataList != null && dataList.size() > 0)
            {
                List dataList  = shipment.getChildren();
                if(dataList != null && dataList.size() > 0)
                {
                    XMLOutputter xmlOutput = new XMLOutputter();
                    String shipmentXml = xmlOutput.outputString(shipment);
                    InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(shipmentXml));
                    org.w3c.dom.Document document = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(source);
                    XPath xpath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

                    String number = (xpath.evaluate("/object/field[@name ='number']", document).trim());
                    String name = (xpath.evaluate("/object/field[@name ='id']", document).trim());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**I'm able to get name and id**

```
<field type="BigIntegerField" name="number">100809206</field>
<field type="CharField" name="id">11700632</field>
```

**but not able to get below fields usimg xpath..**

```
<field name="test123">
        <object pk="1" model="employee">
            <field type="DateTimeField" name="updated_on">27 Nov, 2014, 17:18 hrs</field>
            <field type="CharField" name="EmployeeName">ABC</field>
        </object>
        <object pk="2" model="employee">
            <field type="DateTimeField" name="updated_on">28 Nov, 2014, 17:18 hrs</field>
            <field type="CharField" name="EmployeeName">XYZ</field>
        </object>
 </field>
```

**how to get value "27 Nov, 2014, 17:18 hrs" and ABC using attribute "updated_on and EmployeeName respectively**

this 2 tags are varying can change from 2 to 5 or more..I want to iterate it in for loop
and put it in some bean..so want value based on names of tags in for loop

so..Basically i Want to figure out how many `<object pk="1" model="employee">` tags are available in  `<field name="test123">` and want to iterate over each `<object>` tag in for loop using fields `updated_on and EmployeeName` and get their values and put in java bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to get value "27 Nov, 2014, 17:18 hrs" and ABC using attribute "updated_on and EmployeeName respectively

The correct path expression to get the `field[@type = 'DateTimeField']` is

```
/object/field/object/field[@name = 'updated_on']
```

and to get `field[@type = 'CharField']`

```
/object/field/object/field[@name = 'EmployeeName']
```

---

You do not say *why* you're unable to retrieve those nodes, but I suspect the following: Most likely, you have tried to find them with an expression like

```
/object/field[@name ='updated_on']
```

which would only work if the XML was structured as follows:

```
<object>
  <field name="updated_on"/>
</object>
```

In fact, the structure is

```
<object>
    <field>
        <object>
            <field name="updated_on"/>
        </object>
    </field>
</object>
```

Finding elements anywhere in a tree can only be done with `//`:

```
//object/field[@name ='updated_on']
```